# Is a function to convert an object copying the return value?

Tags: c++, memory-management, reference, copy

In C++, I have a rectangle parameter coming into a function.
Since i'm keeping my system abstract, I made my own Rectangle class.
The function I pass it into (for SFML graphics library) uses its own RectangleShape object.
So, I need to convert my Rectangle into a RectangleShape.

I went to make a function to do this, but I got confused as to what objects are being created, who is getting copied, and what's fastest. Here is the situation:

```
RectangleShape MyClass::ConvertRectangleToRectangleShape(const Rectangle& inRectangle)
{
    Vector2f size(inRectangle.GetWidth(), inRectangle.GetHeight());
    RectangleShape convertedRectangle(size);
    Vector2f position(inRectangle.GetPosition.GetX(), inRectangle.GetPosition.GetY());
    returnShape.SetPosition(position);

    return convertedRectangle;
}

void MyClass::DrawShape(const Rectangle& inRectangle)
{
    // Convert the shape
    RectangleShape convertedShape = ConvertRectangleToRectangleShape(inRectangle);
    // Rest of code here
}
```

So, as you can see, none of my objects come in as pointers. So I don't need to deal with that.

The object I return is on the stack, but not a reference. It gets copied when I return it, right? That line

```
return convertedRectangle;
```

it copies the rectangle shape into the variable I create in the second function

```
RectangleShape convertedShape = ConvertRectangleToRectangleShape(inRectangle);
```

right?

I can't return it as a reference variable, because it gets de-allocated once I leave the scope of the function, right?

```
RectangleShape& MyClass::ConvertRectangleToRectangleShape(const Rectangle& inRectangle)
```

If I can't return it as a reference, and I wouldnt want a copy, would I just have to paste the code into the function? Or #define it? What's the correct way here, or where am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I'd go with an explicit conversion operator and a `static_cast` when the conversion needs to happen.

Comment: Why don't you want a copy? Performance? Sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: @chris as I mentioned below, what happens if I don't have access to the RectangleShape class? Otherwise, thanks for the cool solution!

Comment: @GManNickG It is, but i'm creating this more to learn C++ better

Comment: @chris what if the classes are unrelated?

Comment: @MintyAnt I couldn't understand why chris' suggestion wouldn't work, since if you're able to create a new RectangleShape, it should be do-able in the conversion operator too, no? Since KarthikT's solution also expects you to call the ctor of RectangleShape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your case is more neatly expressed as a [conversion constructor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/compbgpl/v9v111/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp9.bg.doc/language_ref/cplr384.htm)

```
class RectangleShape{
    ....
    RectangleShape(const Rectangle&);
    ...
};
```

Then you would write

```
RectangleShape convertedShape = inRectangle;
```

And it would work as you would expected, without any unnecessary copies or constructions .

This would be *similar* to such a style.

```
RectangleShape convertedShape;
convertedShape.InitFrom(inRectangle);
```

Which would also not need a copy, since it is directly called as a method on the final object.

What chris suggested (if i understand it properly) would require a change on the `class Rectangle`, to allow it to convert itself to a `RectangleShape`.

```
class Rectangle{
    ....
    operator RectangleShape();
    ...
};
```

It would allow for a similarly elegant assignment code, but I am not sure how he intended to convert from one to another without a copy, if they are unrelated classes.

If you are not able to modify `RectangleShape`, the closest I can think of is doing something like this.

```
InitRectangleShape(convertedShape, inRectangle);
....    
void InitRectangleShape(RectangleShape& convertedShape,const Rectangle& inRectangle);
```

Unless I am much mistaken, this is similar to how [Return Value optimization is typically implemented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). Which brings us to the points that other commenters have brought out, It is possible the compiler has already optimized the copy out for you.

Comment: So it's just a copy constructor using a rectangle reference? Cool. What if the RectangleShape is part of an API I cannot access? What are my options then?

Comment: @MintyAnt it is similar to a copy constructor yes, it only differs in name, it is more strictly refered to as a [conversion constructor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/compbgpl/v9v111/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp9.bg.doc/language_ref/cplr384.htm)

Comment: @MintyAnt If you cant change RectangleShape, you can pass an instance of `RectangleShape` within your converter to directly be used.

Comment: @KarthikT: But `RectangleShape` is part of SFML, right? How could one add a new ctor to it?

Comment: @legends2k My answer did not take that into consideration (i had no idea that it was a library class) which is what the OP also mentioned.

Comment: @legends2k SFML is open source, so I can, but i'd rather keep my changes to my side of the code, and was curious what you'd do without an API. Karthik supplied the last solution as a good one

Comment: @KarthikT I think i'll go with your last suggestion, thank you for explaining out everything, it makes this a lot clearer. I have one quick question: I mentioned, in my example, returning a reference to the variable I created in the convert function. That DOES NOT work, because the object goes out of scope, right?

Comment: @MintyAnt: Of course, one should never return a reference to a local object, since it'll get destroyed once the function unwinds/returns. So, yes, in your example, `return convertedRectangle;` will be a disaster if the function's return type is by reference.

Comment: @MintyAnt Im glad i was able to help. As to the returning reference to a local variable, that I believe is Undefined behavior, which means its not expected to work by the standard, but it might work, based on implementation, configuration, phase of the moon etc. **Basically**, dont do it.

Comment: @KarthikT, You got my suggestion, minus the fact that you can stick the `explicit` keyword in there since C++11 to avoid implicit conversions from `Rectangle` to `RectangleShape` happening. I was not concerning myself with the extra copy, and with RVO, you'll most likely only ever have one `Rectangle` (which you start with) and one `RectangleShape` (rather than it being copied out of the function) when converting.